# How can make it work in my activity?

Tags: android

```
public class connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Boolean login
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient()
    FileOutputStream fos = null
    FileInputStream fis = null
    BufferedReader br = null
    StringBuilder text1 = new StringBuilder()

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this)
        pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...")
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false)
        pDialog.setCancelable(true)
        pDialog.show()

    }

    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            client.connect("ftp.byethost12.com")
            // System.out.println(client.getReplyString())
            login = client.login("b12_14535591", "mahdirida")
            // if (login)
            // System.out.println("login complete")

            client.sendCommand(FTPCmd.CHANGE_WORKING_DIRECTORY, "htdocs");
            // System.out.println(client.getReplyString())

            InputStream si = client.retrieveFileStream("json2.txt")
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(si)

            String line
            while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                text1.append(line + "\n")
            }
            //System.out.print(text1.toString())
            Toast.makeText(getParent(), "complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        }

        return null
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        if(pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss()
        text.setText(text1.toString())// show the result
    }

}
```

if i do that in a class and run as android application its work ! but in my activity it does not work

```
    03-28 13:39:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1751): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    03-28 13:39:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1751): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
    03-28 13:39:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
    03-28 13:39:06.473: E/AndroidRuntime(1751):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)

---
```

Edit:

```
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782): Activity com.mahdi.ftpconnect.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d27e80 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mahdi.ftpconnect.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40d27e80 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-456,144} that was originally added here
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:354)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:216)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at com.mahdi.ftpconnect.MainActivity$connect.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:80)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at com.mahdi.ftpconnect.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-29 11:46:25.331: E/WindowManager(782):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 3):

```
 Toast.makeText(getParent(), "complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

you can not run Toast inside `doInBackground`. Use an `Handler` or `runOnUiThread` to make the UI Thread shows it or, as correctly pointed out from `@codeMagic`, you should use the `onPostExecute` callback to run `UI` stuff

Comment: But you don't mean to use runOnUiThread() inside of doInBackground(), correct?

Comment: just to post that line. What's wrong with that in your opinion @codeMagic

Comment: Personally, I've just seen a lot of mistakes come out of it from posts on here. Technically, it may work but I just have seen it cause a lot of confusion and more errors. And since `AsyncTask` has methods to handle this, it seems like bad practice, IMHO. So it seems that since the OP already has an `AsyncTask` set up then using `onProgressUpdate()` or `onPostExecute()` is a better solution

Comment: I could agree, but what kind of errors are you talking about?

Comment: To be honest, I would have to look through some posts (which I will do if I have time in a little bit) so I can't give specifics right now but I know I have seen it cause people grief. And I just cringe when I see people do that since the `AsyncTask` class is set up to handle it in it's own ways

Comment: [Here is one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941703/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-at-android-os-strictmodeandroidblockgua/19941745#19941745) though to be fair, they were using it incorrectly. But that was kind of my point is that it just adds one more (unnecessary) thing to break. I know you understand that but just for reference.

Comment: I remember the post you just posted... I do not know, I did not used AsyncTask that much. I agree on what you said *just adds one more (unnecessary) thing to break.*, but if used with just amount of brain usually it does not break :D

Comment: "but if used with just amount of brain usually it does not break " haha I guess that's true! I suppose I should have started with "just adds one more (unnecessary) thing to break." I did make it sound like it natively draws errors at first.

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
Toast.makeText(getParent(), "complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You cannot show toast in `doInbackground`. This is one mistake. You need to post full stacktrace further.

You can use either use `runOnUiThread` which is a method of Activity or return result in `doInbackground` and update ui in `onPostExecute` which is invoked on ui thread.

Comment: j'ai dit en haut .. i have said above , no problem in my code when i trying this code into a class and run it , but inside an activity , its not working .

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(804): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Note : the text file are not emty

Comment: @user3425322 you need to post the full stacktrace for further help.