# My Asyntask is not working when I put it inside a separate java file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I had all my asynctask in a single file, but it was getting a bit messy so I decide to put them in their separate files/classes. I keep getting a few errors. What am I doing wrong, thanks

**Inside of my mainActivity.and  *Error*:**

```
//Handler for the PIN. Leads to the Internet Intent
public void log_in(View v) {



    new TwitterLogin(null, null, null).execute();

    }

 Description    
    The constructor TwitterLogin() is undefined MainActivity.java
```

**TwitterLogin.java**

```
//Starts an intent that loads up a web browser and asks the user to log in to twitter
// and get a pin#
public class TwitterLogin extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, RequestToken> {

    private Context context;
    private Activity Activity;
    public Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
    public RequestToken requestToken = null;

    public TwitterLogin(Context context, Twitter twitter,
            RequestToken requestToken) {
        this.context = context;
        this.twitter = twitter;
        this.requestToken = requestToken;


    }

    @Override
    protected RequestToken doInBackground(URL... arg0) {

        try {
            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
            Log.i("Got Request Token", "food4thought");
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Log.i("Failed to get Request Token", "food4thought");
        }

        // Log.i(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL(), "food4thought");
        // requestToken.getAuthorizationURL();
        // log_in.setText();

        try {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()));
            context.startActivity(browserIntent);
        }

        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Unable to log in, No access to the Internet.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Here is the logcat

```
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644): Process: com.example.food4thought, PID: 19644
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at com.example.food4thought.TwitterLogin.doInBackground(TwitterLogin.java:39)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at com.example.food4thought.TwitterLogin.doInBackground(TwitterLogin.java:1)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-24 21:27:23.635: E/AndroidRuntime(19644):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: I posted the logcat. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `constructor` takes 3 `params`...the first of which is a `Context`. You have passed `null` to all of these which means you get a `NPE` here

```
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

and here

```
requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
```

and here

```
 Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL()));
```

since `context` is `null`.

You would want to change it to

```
// assuming MainActivity is the name of your Activity
new TwitterLogin(MainActivity.this, null, null).execute();
```

`twitter` and `requestToken` are `null` also and it looks like you reference `twitter` first which would probably give your exception. You are passing `null` for these variables then trying to initialize them with the `null` parameters sent.

**Edit**

This is also a mess because you shouldn't try updating the UI in `doInBackground()`

```
catch (NullPointerException e) {
        ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(),
                        "Unable to log in, No access to the Internet.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Use the methods that `AsyncTask` provides you with.

[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

[Please also see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941703/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-at-android-os-strictmodeandroidblockgua/19941745#19941745)